# Stuck in grub rescue after 13.04 installer crashed

Tags: 13.04

So I created a live usb for 13.04 using lili usb  creator on Windows. During the installation process, the installer crashed with some 'apt failure to get data from cd rom'.

Now I'm stuck with Grub rescue and can't boot into windows 7 either since I can't get a fully functional grub.

What do I do to rectify this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have broken packages on the USB, did you run disk test before installing?
You can try 
 dpkg --configure -a 
 in command line as root from rescue and then 
 apt-get update

 apt-get dist-upgrade

 
  Or just reinstall the disk if you have fresh installation.
 
 Check if your USB drive works well.

Comment: Problem was corrupted live usb. Just installed perfectly with a dvd

Answer (score 1):

same thing happened to me, this helped me out: [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Just boot in to the live cd/usb add the repository and install boot-repair. than follow the commands you get (quit a lot of copy pasting) after that it worked.